# React Native Connect Redux Action & Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been trying to connect my Redux Action and Reducer to my component. But it doesn't seem to work properly.

Currently, when I call my Action, it does get to that Action but it does not move onto my reducer. I think I am missing something here but having a hard time finding out what is the issue.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Here is my Action:

```
export const getItem = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    debugger;
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_REQUEST',
      options: {
        method: 'GET',
        endpoint: `18.222.137.195:3000/v1/item?offset=0`,
        actionTypes: {
          success: types.GET_ITEM_SUCCESS,
          loading: types.GET_ITEM_LOADING,
          error: types.GET_ITEM_SUCCESS
        }
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Here is my Reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
 getItem: {}
};

const registerItemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case types.GET_ITEM_LOADING:
   debugger;
   return { ...state, loading: true, data: null };

  case types.GET_ITEM_SUCCESS:
   debugger;
   return { ...state, loading: false, getItem: action.data};

  case types.GET_ITEM_ERROR:
   debugger;
   return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.data};

  default: {
   return state;
  }
 }
}
export default registerItemReducer;
```

Here is my store:

```
/* global window */
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'; // default: 
localStorage if web, AsyncStorage if react-native
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

// Redux Persist config
const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  blacklist: ['status'],
};

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, reducers);

const middleware = [thunk];

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(
    store,
    null,
    () => { store.getState(); },
  );

  return { persistor, store };
};

export default configureStore;
```

Lastly here is my component that has "connect" part & componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItem();
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  registerItem: state.registerItem || {},
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getItem: getItem
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterItemComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is registerItem name of your reducer? Your reducer has two state getItem and loading. But in the below code you are calling state.registerItem. Looks like there is some mismatch between the actual state and the mapped state.

In the code below, try to print the state value, it will help you to navigate to the exact parameter you are looking for.

Add the below line in your existing code to debug:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 console.log("State of reducer" + JSON.stringify(state));
 registerItem: state.registerItem || {},
});
```